# Incomplete ticks in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am changing the ticks for an imshow plot manually but the new ticks is incomplete and does not go through all the range that it has. What is the reason?

Here is a simple version of my code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randn(30,50)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
x_range = np.around((np.arange(50)/10.) / np.sqrt(5.5), decimals=2)
y_range = np.around((np.arange(30)/10.) / np.sqrt(2.5), decimals=2)
plt.imshow(a)
ax.set_xticklabels(x_range)
ax.set_yticklabels(y_range)
plt.show()
```

and here is the result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be more precise in your question and provide a code that fully describes your problem. Of course you can address single plots, but you need to pass plot indices then!

```
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
    x_range = np.around((np.arange(50)/15.) / np.sqrt(5.5), decimals=2)
    y_range = np.around((np.arange(30)/15.) / np.sqrt(2.5), decimals=2)
    x_range2 = np.around((np.arange(5)/15.) / np.sqrt(5.5), decimals=2)
    y_range2 = np.around((np.arange(3)/15.) / np.sqrt(5.5), decimals=2)
    ax[0].imshow(a,extent=[min(x_range),max(x_range),min(y_range),max(y_range)])
    ax[1].imshow(a,extent=[min(x_range2),max(x_range2),min(y_range2),max(y_range2)])
    ax[0].set_xticks(x_range)
    ax[1].set_xticks(x_range2)
    ax[0].set_yticks(y_range)
    ax[1].set_yticks(y_range2)
```

Also be aware of that `set_xticklabels()` only changes the actual naming of the label, where `set_xticks()` also refers to the real position in your plot.

Comment: I thought I am precise enough by using `plt.subplots(1, 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to replace

```
plt.imshow(a)
ax.set_xticklabels(x_range)
ax.set_yticklabels(y_range)
```

by

```
plt.imshow(a,extent=[min(x_range),max(x_range),min(y_range),max(y_range)])
plt.xticks(x_range)
plt.yticks(y_range)
```

Comment: That works for plots but not for subplots. When I have more than one plot then it only affects one when I use xticks!